# Is there a naming convention for initial values?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, pep8

Python has a style guide ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) that I try to follow in my code, yet I couldn't find information on this.

I need to define variables to store the **initial** value of other variables. I want to be consistent throughout the code, so I need to choose a convention. What would be the best way to name them, following PEP 8 and Clean Code?

Examples of variables: `population`, `migration_rate`, `birth_rate`, `healthcare_costs`...

Should I use: `initial_population` ? `migration_rate_start`? `birth_rate_init`? `healthcare_costs_at_start_time`?

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you I guess. Names and structure. I would do the following:

```
CONFIG_INITIAL_STATE = {
    'population': 100,
    'migration_rate': 0.5,
    ...
    }
```

Keys correspond to function argument names. And then I simply pass appropriate dictionaries to function calls.

```
some_func(arg_1, arg_2, **CONFIG_INITIAL_STATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are module-level constants then the PEP-8 convention is to use [`UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants).